# How to make a thread accessible from another thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have two thread, `taskThread`, a thread with a long-running task, and a `timerThread`, a recurrent timer every n milliseconds. I am trying to trigger any function call on `taskThread` from `timerThread`.

```
@Override
public Task<List<Schedule>> createTask() {
    return new Task<List<Schedule>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<Schedule> call() throws Exception {
                Task currentTask = this;
                Thread taskThread = Thread.currentThread();     //Thread-1,Task thread
                Timer checker = new Timer();
                checker.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            if(currentTask.isDone()) cancel();
                            System.out.println("Task thread "+taskThread+" is : "+taskThread.getState());
                            System.out.println("Timer thread" + Thread.currentThread()+" is : "+Thread.currentThread().getState());
                            taskThread.wait();  //throws IllegalMonitorStateException
                            Thread.sleep(300);
                            Thread.currentThread().notifyAll();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex){
                            System.out.println(ex);
                        }
                    }
                },0,500);
                List<Schedule> result = solveMakespan(this);    //Blocking call
                checker.cancel();   //cancel timer
                return result;
        }
    };
}
```

The scenario I am trying to achieve, is making the `taskThread` wait for the `timerThread` before continuing, I read about synchronized blocks but I am not sure how to make the timer block acquire the lock since the `solveMakespan` is declared outside its thread, and declaring it inside the timer would make it execute multiple times.

EDIT : Concerning the nuance about "accessing the task's thread", I'd like to either be able to call .wait() or join() on the *Thread* that I want to wait from the Timer thread, or for the Task instance to provide a method that would run on its existing thread, but triggerable from the timer instance. The code snippet should hopefully make the goal I'm trying to achieve clear.

Comment: Your question confuses somewhat as "threads" don't access other "threads", but rather objects call methods of other objects.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, I guess the correct term would be "accessing the Task's instance belonging to Thread-1 from the TimerTask's thread", you're welcome to edit my question to clarify it as I feel like I do not have the knowledge to write it in a non-confusing manner

Comment: Your question, so much better for you to clarify it

Comment: are you talking about `Future` class?

Comment: Yes, the [Task](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) here implements Future. The function createTask() is called from a [Service](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) class.

Comment: I would use a `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition` to signal the task thread to continue.